# Take end point of a short Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to know how to take the endpoint of a short when I give the name to it instead of the middle point.
For example, in this case, I have a short that I called "c" and it is long 2.5. But then when I use the node c to start a new drawing it starts from the midpoint of the short (so at 1.25) but I want to start from 2.5.

```
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) to[short, name=c] ++(2.5,0) to[C=$C_C$] ++(0,-1.5) node[ground]{};
  \draw (c) to[short, -o] +(1,0) node[right](vout){$V_{out}$};
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want the name of the element "short", you want the coordinate of the end point of the element:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[short] ++(2.5,0) coordinate(c) to[C=$C_C$] ++(0,-1.5) node[ground]{};
    \draw (c) to[short, -o] +(1,0) node[right](vout){$V_{out}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

and now, a *secret*:

there is an internal coordinate name `nameend` (and `namestart`) that point to the start and the end of the path. You should **not** use them, however, they are undocumented and the name can change or be overridden.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[short, name=myshort] ++(2.5,0) coordinate(c) to[C=$C_C$] ++(0,-1.5) node[ground]{};
    \draw (c) to[short, -o] +(1,0) node[right](vout){$V_{out}$};
    \node [color=red, ocirc] at (myshortend) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, another small secret :-): if you do not use decorations (currents, poles, labels, etc.) `to[short]` is exactly the same as `--`.